# What is Wrong with my JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am using the jquery function $.getJson. It is sending the data I want and the PHP script producing the JSON is working as it should. However, the problem I am having occurs from here.

In my $.getJSON code, I want it to simply log the results if successful and log as an error if an error... You guessed it... I'm getting an error...

Here is my JSON code being passed to it that is producing the error but I can not see what is wrong with it....

```
  {
"results":{
"city":[
    "metric":"visits",
    "dimension":"city",
    "data":[["London","5"],["Glasgow","3"],["(not set)","1"],["Aberdeen","1"],["Antalya","1"]]
    ],

"browser":[
    "metric":"visits",
    "dimension":"browser",
    "data":[["Internet Explorer","11"],["Chrome","9"],["Firefox","3"],["Safari","3"],["Android Browser","2"]]
    ],

"screenResolution":[
    "metric":"visits",
    "dimension":"screenResolution",
    "data":[["1280x800","5"],["1680x1050","4"],["1024x768","3"],["1366x768","3"],["1280x1024","2"]]
    ]
    }
    }
```

UPDATED TO SHOW CODE

This is my code used for getting the results

```
$.ajax({

//DEFINE URL being called by Ajax
url:'./getAnalytics.php',
dataType: "json",
data:{dateToSearch:dateToSearch},
success:function(resultsToView){

console.log(resultsToView);


},error:function(resultsToView){
console.log("Error: " + resultsToView);
}
});
```

And the console shows:
[image: Result of resultsToView]

When I get this back, the error function is called rather than success.
Please help.

Comment: what is the status code returned?

Comment: Lint it before posting - http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [JSON](http://json.org/) *is* invalid. The square brackets denote an *array* (list), where the items do not have keys. Change

```
[
  "metric":"visits",
  "dimension":"…",
  …
]
```

to *object* (map) syntax with curly braces:

```
{
  "metric":"visits",
  "dimension":"…",
  …
}
```

---

Also, the error callback has the signature `Function(jqXHR xhr, String textStatus, String errorThrown)`. You're logging the stringification of the `xhr` object, which is not helpful. Better use

```
…,
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Error: "+error+" ("+status+")", xhr);
}
```

Comment: he also has it two more times for `"browser": [
            "metric": "visits",` and `"screenResolution": [
            "metric": "visits",`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ: Sure, but I'm not going to write out the full JSON :-)

Comment: :P  that'll fix them all though +1

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @Bergi and the JSONLint is bloody usefu

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON isn't valid. E.g.

```
"city":[
```

should be:

```
"city":{
```

[ is for arrays.

You can use a JSON validator to check whether your JSON is good e.g. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Nice that you also included a validator link